# Auto toggle between isometric when using 1, 3, and 7

Tags: 3d-view

Previously, I've always had a setting or something which would always switch to isometric view whenever the view is moved to front, left, or top view (with 1, 3, and 7), and automatically switch back whenever i pan away.

Comment: do you mean orthographic view? because the definition of isometric view would make it impossible to have for all front, left, or top views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `2.79` and older versions that would be the Auto Perspective setting. You can find it in the preferences under `Interface`.

[image: auto perspective option]

If you are using `2.8` and later versions, it's now under `Navigation` then `Orbit and Pan` (it's enabled by default):

[image]